# if $(k+m)^n + (l+m)^n = (k+l+m)^n$ then $kl$ divides $m^n$

Tags: factoring

How to prove that for any $k, l, m, n \in \Bbb N$ and $n \ge 3 $ with $(k+m)^n + (l+m)^n = (k+l+m)^n$  then $kl$ divides $m^n$?

As a special case, in the same way as Brian's answer below it can be shown that if $a^n + b^n = (a+k)^n$ then $k$ divides $b^n$:
$$a^n + b^n = (a+k)^n = a^n + k^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i}a^ik^{n-i}\\ = a^n + k^n + k\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i}a^ik^{n-i-1} \\= a^n + k \left(k^{n-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i}a^ik^{n-i-1}\right) $$ so
$$  b^n = k \left(k^{n-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i}a^ik^{n-i-1}\right) $$
thus $k$ divides $b^n$ and furthermore $ rad(k) $ divides $b$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Use the binomial theorem to expand both sides of the original equation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}i\left(k^i+\ell^i\right)m^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}i(k+\ell)^im^{n-i}\,.$$

Pull out the $m^n$ terms:

$$2m^n+\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}i\left(k^i+\ell^i\right)m^{n-i}=m^n+\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}i(k+\ell)^im^{n-i}\,,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
m^n&=\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}im^{n-i}\left((k+\ell)^i-\left(k^i+\ell^i\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}im^{n-i}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\binom{i}jk^j\ell^{i-j}\\
&=k\ell\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}im^{n-1}\sum_{j-1}^{i-1}\binom{i}jk^{j-1}\ell^{i-j-1}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am impressed! A very clear-cut use of the binomial theorem. The inner $l^j$ and $k^j$ cancel out. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Peter: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

By Fermat's last theorem (yes, not Fermat's little theorem) one of $k+m$ and $l+m$ is zero, which means that $m=0$ and one of $k$ and $l$ is zero. It follows that $kl=0$ and $m^n=0$; $0\mid0$ and the statement is true.

Comment: Funnily enough, I recall a bogus proof of Fermat's Last Theorem being linked on Math SE recently. This result I think was a lemma used by the author as part of their marvelously elementary proof. So I guess technically your argument is circular :P

Comment: @jlammy Oh come on, I am.not referring to bogus proofs of Fermat's last theorem, only Wiles's.

Comment: @jlammy: At which step is it bogus? I would very much like to know. Please let me know.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the real "insightful solution" for this problem that indicates what really happens for the constraints rather than proving a lot of "false implies anything" cases. .

Comment: @cr001 Does this mean that because the initial condition cannot be fulfilled the implication is wrong? so how does a proof by contradiction work then?

Comment: @Peter Consider a similar simple problem. "Suppose n is an integer that satisfies $n=m^2$ where m is an integer and $n\leq 0$. Prove that n is not of the form $4k+3$. "  The insightful proof is that  n can only be $0$ which is not $4k+3$. However there might be other proofs like since $m^2=(2x)^2=4k$ or $m^2=(2y+1)^2=4k+1$ we have $m^2$ is not $4k+3$; these proofs do not catch what the constraint really implies. I know this is a bad example but I I hope you get the point.

Comment: @cr001 Unfortunately I don't get your point. I understand that the initial condition cannot be met because of FLT. But in a context where FLT may not be used, e,g. in a proof (by contradiction) of the FLT, he question must be proved by others means.

Comment: @Peter In a classroom context, it's reasonable to say "FLT may not be used." But to really understand the problem, it's important to realize $m=0$ is the only case possible. Some proofs simply show the result is correct without giving insights, while some other proofs provide understanding of what's really happening. For example quantum physics, the formula is there but no one really knows what's really happening behind the formula. That's all I can say.